# canvas toDataURL() returns transparent image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I am attempting to use a chrome extension to take a screenshot of the current page, and then draw some shapes on it. After I have done that to the image, I turn the whole thing into a canvas that way it is all together, like the divs I have drawn on it are now baked into the 'image', and they are one in the same. After doing this, I want to turn the canvas back into a png image I can use to push to a service I have, but when I go to use the `canvas.toDataURL()` in order to do so, the image source that it creates is completely transparent. If I do it as a jpeg, it is completely black.

I read something about the canvas being 'dirtied' because I have drawn an image to it, and that this won't work in Chrome, but that doesn't make sense to me as I have gotten it to work before, but I am unable to use my previous method. Below is the code snippet that isn't working. I am just making a canvas element, and then I am drawing an image before that.

```
var passes = rectangles.length;
var run = 0;
var context = hiDefCanvas.getContext('2d');

while (run < passes) {
  var rect = rectangles[run];
  // Set the stroke and fill color
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,255,130,0.7)';
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.1)';
  context.rect(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height);               
  context.setLineDash([2,1]);
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  run++;
} // end of the while loop
screencapImage.className = 'hide';
context.fill();
context.stroke();
console.log(hiDefCanvas.toDataURL());
```

And the image data that it returns is: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACWAAAAVGCAYAAAAaGIAxAAAgAElEQ…ECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAQBVKBUe32pNYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC which is a blank, transparent image.

Is there something special I need to do with Chrome? Is there something that I am missing? Thanks, I appreciate the time and help.

Comment: Does it show the screen properly when you comment out this section that draws rectangles on top of it?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Are you asking me if the canvas renders correctly without any of the rectangles? If so, the answer is yes, it does render the image on the canvas correctly.

Comment: I don't actually think I can help unless I can see all your relevant code. With just this, the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I found some other issues whilst looking through the code, so I may be able to stumble upon a fix. I'm unable to post all the code, I am sorry. I appreciate your time though.

Comment: Do you see a security error in your console? If so, it's the "tainted" issue. If not, you are likely drawing rectangles across the entire image then filling them in which causes the image to be empty.

Comment: @MikeC No, I do not see a security warning, and I don't think that I am drawing rectangles across the entirety of the canvas.

Comment: **Blind guess !** (I love those) are you drawing only at values > 300 width & 150 height? Then you are setting your canvas width height by CSS which is bad. Second try : are you playing with ctx.globalAlpha ?

Comment: @Kaiido I am drawing at any size less than 1200 (w) * 675 (h), I think that I am setting the width and height by CSS, and globalAplha rings a bell, I worked with that a month and a half ago, but I don't know if I'm using it anymore... should I be?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, and found the solution here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749824

"I can confirm, that it works if you set preserveDrawingBuffer.

var glContextAttributes = { preserveDrawingBuffer: true };
var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", glContextAttributes);"

After getting the context with preserveDrawingBuffer, toDataURL just works as expected, no completely transparent or black image.

Comment: I have same problem.
In ubuntu chrome & FF works fine w/o `preserveDrawingBuffer`, but in Win10 in chrome and Opera in ubuntu returns transparent image also with `preserveDrawingBuffer`. And what is very interesting that in Win10 edge(ie) also return image from canvas, not transparent one.

Comment: Worked for me!

    `var glContextAttributes = { preserveDrawingBuffer: true };`
    `var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", glContextAttributes);`

Answer (score 2):

Having a similar problem I found a solution, thanks to the following post
https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas/issues/29.

These methods return a promise, so you would need to wait for it to resolve before the variable can be populated.
My solution was to set asyn function and await for the result:

```
const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("myCanvas")[0];
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let img = new Image();
img.onload = async (e) => { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); ctx.font = "165px Arial";ctx.fillStyle = "white"; b64Code = await (<any>canvas).toDataURL(); }
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to fix a longtime problem on Openlayers, with a custom WMS loader that the user could change brightness, contrast and alpha of the loaded image.